# importing nested JSON to Google Spreadsheets

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi!
I'm trying to import data from a nested JSON into Google spreadsheets. I use code that has worked perfectly with another nested JSON but now I'm getting the JSON from a different API and it looks slightly different and it throws a "The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid. (line 18, file "Code")"-error, referring to the line;

```
dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, rows.length, 5);
```

I use the following code;

```
function getHistoricalRatesETH() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheets = ss.getSheets();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("getData");
    ss.setSpreadsheetLocale('en-us');
    var url="https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday?fsym=ETH&tsym=USD&limit=1460"; 
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url); // get feed
    var dataAll = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); //
    var dataSet = dataAll;
    var rows = [],data;
    for (i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) {
        data = dataSet[i];
        rows.push([data.time,data.close,data.high,data.low,data.open]);
    }
    dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, rows.length, 5); //Last digit denotes columns
    dataRange.setValues(rows);
    ss.setSpreadsheetLocale('en-us');
}
```

I tried to change

```
var rows = [],data;
```

to

```
var rows = [],Data;
```

Also tried using the ids

```
rows.push([data.Data.time,data.Data.close,data.Data.high,data.Data.low,data.Data.open]);
```

But the result is the same.

I've tripple-checked so the sheet name isn't misspelt and 
searched like crazy on how to address a nested json but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the data you want at `response.Data`. So how about the following modification for your script?

#### From :

```
var dataSet = dataAll;
```

#### To :

```
var dataSet = dataAll.Data;
```